# Android Instant Apps (Games) using Phaser?

Tags: android, html, google-play-games, phaser-framework, android-instant-apps

Is there any way to use Phaser (HTML5 Game framework) for Android Instant Apps? It's quite easy to make it for Facebook Instant Apps as well as for native Android/iOS using Cordova, but how about Android Instant Apps? Can't find the information and/or any tutorial online.

Comment: I haven't do that myself, but have you check [this link](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/game-instant-app)?

Comment: @ManuelAbascal yes, I've checked that link before already. There's nothing mentioned about HTML5/Phaser/Web/JavaScript/hybrid solutions, it describes only how to develop it using native technologies.